# Is it possible to reset SA password without stopping SQL Server Service?

Tags: sql-server-2014, windows-server, command-line, service-accounts, password-recovery

I lost a password for sa account. Now I want to reset SA password and at the same time not to restart SQL Server Service or going into single-user mode. I would like to mention that I am windows administrator, so I can run command line as admin. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a sysadmin role member account besides `sa` (Windows or SQL Server login), you can connect using that account to change the `sa` password without a restart. But if `sa` is only the sysadmin role member, a service restart is required as part of [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not belong to sysadmin role

Comment: What service account is running the SQL Service?  If you can impersonate that then you may be able to log in as that user and then change the password that way.